# Variables not getting string from input Dialog

Tags: java, dialog, null

I'm trying to get the input of a dialog box using method `charEdit` that should change the input but instead the variables still equal null at the end.

```
public String showInputDialog(String stringy)
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,stringy);
    if(input == null || input.isEmpty())
    {
        input = showInputDialog(stringy);
    }
    return input;
}

public void charEdit(Checkbox chara,String account,String password){
    chara.setLabel(showInputDialog("Character Name?"));
    account=(showInputDialog("Account Name?"));
    password=(showInputDialog("Account Password?"));
    chara.setEnabled(true);
}

public void menuItemSelected(MenuItem menuObj){
    if (menuObj==help){
        messageBox("Edit character info and then click the login button");
    }
    else if (menuObj==charOneEdit){
        charEdit(characterOne,charAArray[0],charPArray[0]);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't variable characterOne keep it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Strings are immutable. So calling this method:

```
public void charEdit(Checkbox chara,String account,String password){
    chara.setLabel(showInputDialog("Character Name?"));
    account=(showInputDialog("Account Name?"));
    password=(showInputDialog("Account Password?"));
    chara.setEnabled(true);
}
```

will not change the Strings referred to by the arguments that were passed in to the method.

In other words, calling this:

```
String acct = "";
String password = ""; // passwords should not be held in Strings by the way
charEdit(something, acct, password);
```

will not change acct or password.

One solution is to use class fields, and change those. Another is to pass in a reference to an object that has fields for account and password, and then you change the state of its fields.

Comment: By the way i like the "Reflection is black magic voodoo" comment xD